# Youtube in Silverlight API

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, youtube

I want to play Youtube video's in a Silverlight application. With that I want to control the player itself too and catch events like when it's done playing.

Is there any good API to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution that looks like it should work: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/mcs/archive/2011/06/10/embedding-youtube-in-silverlight-application.aspx